Examples of Problems in Statistics Accessible only Using Information Geometry
I am just curious if there are some examples of problems in statistics that is indeed accessible using information geometry while proofs completely avoiding geometry is unknown. In other words, problems solved by considering the statistical model $\mathcal{P}$ in the problem as a statistical manifold and then using results in differential geometry while proofs not really using the manifold structure is yet to be discovered.
Same question on cross validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/655707/examples-of-problems-in-statistics-accessible-only-using-information-geometry, but receives up to now no response.

Also asked & answered at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/480903/examples-of-problems-in-statistics-accessible-only-using-information-geometry
